# How to pass parameter this format /search?q=tv

Tags: angular7

I am new to angular7 and my task is to make `/search?q=tv`
I know

```
path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent
```

but the format will be like `search/q`
there is anyway to do it like `search?q`

Comment: I believe your route will be just `path: 'search'` and that's it. Read this: https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Comment: it worked thank you